# API to distinguish between San serif and Serif font

Tags: fonts

I am working extensively on fonts and I need to make a decision based on whether font is serif or san serif.
Is their any api available for that, such that I pass the Font name and its returns me its type?

Answer (score -1):

just look if the font has feet or not
Serif has feet
Sans serif does not

> Or use tools to read the ttf spec of the fonts
>   https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/

Comment: By looking I can distinguish easily. Please read the problem statement and share me if you have some existing solution or link.